# datatable get specific column from row

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following:

```
//a datatable with some rows and columns lets say 5x5
var datatable = new DataTable(); 
var numberofrows = datatable.rows.count;

for (int i = 0; i < numberofrows; i++) {
 //for each row, get the 3rd column
 var cell = datatable.rows[i].???
}
```

how do I get the 3rd column for each row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for 3rd column

```
var cellValue = datatable.Rows[i][2];
```

better, if you know the column name,

```
var cellValue = datatable.Rows[i]["column_name"];
```

Comment: what type of datatype is the cell? I need to use that instead of 'var' so I can get the inner value

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, it depends upon what is the type of column. When you are creating a column (adding column in datatable.Columns.Add(..) ), you get overload the specify type.

Comment: i see, ok I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

If the table contains 2 columns "Property" and "Value". Contents can be inserted as follows

```
table.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));    

table.Rows.Add("P1", "abc");
table.Rows.Add("P2", "xyz");
```

To retrive contents of specific column

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
      if (row["Property"].ToString() == "P1")
         {
             var value = row["Value"].ToString();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

we can read the particular column values by like this

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    if (table.TableName == "Table1")
                    {

                        for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {


                                 int a =  Convert.ToInt32( table.Rows[j].ItemArray[3]);
                                 int b = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[j].ItemArray[4]);




                        }
                    }


                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate thru the datatable and get every row, which can be thought as an array, so you can pick each element of that particular row using an index (and can also use the name of the column instead of the index, i.e.:   row["column3 name"]).

```
foreach(DataRow row in datatable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[2]);
}
```

Comment: thank you but I don't want to use a foreach loop because I want to skip some rows based on index